# CherryPy :: grafting wsgigateway vs adding it to routes dispatcher

Tags: python, wsgi, cherrypy

I am new to cherrypy, and am moving code from pylons to cherrypy ... I have a WSGIGateway object that i graft onto my cherrypy tree.

```
cherrypy.tree.graft(mygatewayobj, '/foo/')
```

I also have a routes dispatcher

```
dispatcher.connect(route = '/foo', name ='foocontroller', controller = mygatewayobj)
```

Should I have both connections for the gateway, or is this redundancy a possible reason for my unexpected, error-message-less crashes? Also, if I do need to graft, should it be

```
/foo/ or /foo?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of `routesDispatcher.connect()` is very poor compared to `cherrypy.graft.tree()`.

I did some benchmark test for cherrypy and the results I got was completely unexpected.
The RPS drops down to nearly half when you try to use cherrypy's `RouteDispatcher` mechanism to route the URL. I was able to get around 2500 RPS when using `cherrypy.graft.tree()` and the RPS drops to around 1100 when using the routes dispatcher.

My suggestion will be to go with `cherrypy.graft.tree()` as it allows you to add URL on the fly without doing a config update and is also much faster.

Comment: Are you sure you're not actually talking about `cherrypy.tree.graft()` instead of `cherrypy.graft.tree()`, which does not seem to exist?